# Copy of existing Plunkr

Tags: plunker

Today, i found one interesting `plunker`, after alot of searching on google found nothing, hope here i will find my answer. i juts want a copy of that plunker. i don't wanna use `copy and paste` technique. is there any method to get copy of well established plunk ? how can i copy whole existing plunker to my new plunker ?

```
i did use `Fork` option of the plunker but not satisfied.
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with the 'fork' option? It is designed for exactly the sort of scenario you mention.

Comment: I am agreed with @filearts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plunker does not provide this mechanism on purpose. You can, of course, recreate a plunk by manually copying and pasting. However, Plunker is designed as a community and forking is a mechanism to show attribution and track the origins of code.

Comment: yeah i know the copy and paste but i am looking for something like whole copy of plunk in single go. btw thnks for answer.